# Any possibility to use Graphics.DrawString on a 1bpp Bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, gdi

The question is quite self explicative, I would like to use a 1bpp Bitmap because will help me (a lot) talking with a device that accept 1bbp bitmaps (well, 160x43 byte array that is a 160x43 bitmap image with 1bpp format).

While C# allows me to create 1bpp bitmaps, I would like to work on it with a Graphics object. But the program seems to behave strangely when I do **any** operation on this.

Is possible to do some graphic operations on those type of bitmaps?

my code snippet is quite short:

```
    Bitmap bwImage = new Bitmap(160, 43, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bwImage))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, 160, 43));
            g.DrawString("ciao sono francesco", Font, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0f, 0f, 159f, 42f));
        }
```

When I do anything related to bitmaps after those calls. My bitmaps doesn't change (obviusly I'm talking about other bitmaps). Like if GDI is totally dead

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Graphics` class and the `Graphics.FromImage` method do not support indexed bitmaps. Please refere to the documentation for the `Graphics.FromImage` method on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage). A workaround for your problem would be to do all graphic operations on a supported bitmap format such as `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` and then convert the bitmap to a indexed bitmap. The conversion is straightforward. You will find a example of such a conversion [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906075741/http://bobpowell.net/onebit.aspx).

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the answer. Also for 4bpp and 8bpp :\